# How to update a function of other class from another class

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, overriding

I can call a function from other class but can't update/overwrite it from other class. is there any way to update a function of other class in different file from other class's function in different file.
thanks

```
file A.php

    class FPDF{

        function header{

            //some code

        }

    }

file B.php

    Class Users extents basecontroller{

        function viewPDF{

            require_once(A.php)

            $pdf = new FPDF

            $pdf->Header()

        }

    }

    require_once(A.php);
    Class PDF extends FPDF
    {
        // Page header
        function Header()
        {
            // Logo
            // Line break
            $this->Ln(100);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Show a small example of what you want to achieve

Comment: Could you please provide a brief code excerpt? Are you sure about the class you're trying to extend is not a `final` one?

Comment: What do you mean by the update, do you want to change the code of that function or just want to execute that function or what? Please specify with some code snippet.

Comment: what you mean by update a function of other class.Please ask question properly and show Piece of code where you stuck

Comment: I am using codeigniter framwork, i used require to include that file which contains the function i need to update. and it shows error if i use extent that class, it says constant fpdf already defined

Comment: i want to change the code @ashok gujjar, because my select query result is in codigniter controller, and i am unable to send it to fpdf file which have a function called header. so i want to change the code of that header function in my controller where i have select query result.

Comment: You can override that function by extending class which have this function and redeclare the same function with the same arguments in your class, that's it.
But make sure class you extend is not final class and function is not a private function.

Comment: extending class not working it says error that "constant fpdf already defined"

Comment: You can rewrite A.php  as codeigniter style library or model and use it : $this->load->model('A'); $this->A->Header();`

Comment: @Danial at least, `require_once(A.php)`

Comment: i wrote this in my file B.php
require_once('./assets/js/pdfCreator/fpdf.php');
class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Page header
function Header()
{
    // Logo
    // Line break
    $pdf->Ln(30);
}
}
but the header function doesn't updated why?

Comment: is that a tough question? I just want the header() function to run with my query result which i can't do in file A because query result is in file B

Comment: fix your formatting. make different code blocks for the different files so they aren't under one code block as it stands. right now it seems like there are two files, but there might be three - its hard to tell. focus on making your question clear if you want an answer.

Comment: Fixed formatting can i have solution now please? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the structer of your files should be something as

```
file A.php
    class FPDF{
        function header{
            //some code
        }
    }


file library/Pdf.php
    require_once(A.php);
    Class Pdf extends FPDF
    {
        // Page header
        function Header()
        {
            // Logo
            // Line break
            $this->Ln(100);
        }
     }  


file Users.php
    Class Users extents basecontroller{
        function viewPDF{
            $this->load->library('pdf');
            $this->pdf->Header()
        }
    }
```

Comment: the header function is calling automatically from many different functions in file A.php i dont want header funciion to run 1 time only from library. i want when ever the header function runs, the updated header function from runtime should appear each time the header function executes.

Comment: if you are unable to solve this, lets consider file A.php and file users.php only. Suppose I have written some code and query in header in file A.php, how can i send where criteria from file users.php to file A.php?

Comment: If you don't change a code of file A, you cant force that code to use your extended header function. But if you create object of class "pdf" any call to it will use new header function, even in the code of file A.

Comment: I have managed to do this other way round, i declared session variable in file users.php and used that in file A.php. but still curious about this that why function header is not overriding at runtime. there should be a way to run same function with different value assigned at runtime.